# ReactJS error is "This component must be used inside a <RecoilRoot> component."

Tags: reactjs, next.js, state, recoiljs

But I'm twisting it slightly, where I don't have a layout but rather a per page component that I'd like to add to the header.

I am getting the following error:
[image]

**Account.jsx** looks something like this:

```
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { userProfile } from "../../../recoil";

export default function Account() {
    const profile = useRecoilValue(userProfile);

    return (
        <div className="w-screen h-full ">
            <header>
                <Navbar profile={dataMe} />
            </header>
            <main className="h-screen relative">
                <div className='h-screen flex bg-gray-bg my-15 static'>
                    <div className='w-full mt-10 m-auto bg-white rounded-lg border'>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <dataMe />
                            </div>

                            <DetailAccount />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div >
    );
};
```

Comment: Could you provide link to the repo?

Comment: Are you using it inside a <RecoilRoot> component?

Comment: Can you share your App.js or App.jsx file?

Comment: Did the answer solve Your problem?

Answer (score 1):

To use [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/getting-started) (*A state management library for React*) properly You have to add `RecoilRoot` wrap component(s). As we can read in documentation :

> Components that use recoil state need `RecoilRoot` to appear somewhere
> in the parent tree.
> A good place to put this is in your root component

**Example** from *official [docs](https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/getting-started)*

```
import React from 'react';
import Account from './Account.jsx';
import {
  RecoilRoot,
  atom,
  selector,
  useRecoilState,
  useRecoilValue,
} from 'recoil';

function App() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <ComponentsThatUseRecoilState />
      {/* in Your case <Account /> component */}
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your component(s) inside the `RecoilRoot` if you want the component to be using the Recoil functionality. As of documentations: https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/RecoilRoot/

So you have to wrap your code inside `<RecoilRoot>` before you can use the `useRecoilValue` hook.

Example:

```
import {RecoilRoot} from 'recoil';

function AppRoot() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <ComponentThatUsesRecoil />
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}
```

It's recommended to use this on root (`App.tsx` or what ever your root element is called) so all your other components can use the Recoil hooks as intended without having to wrap your components in a `RecoilRoot` every single time.